# Automatically generate static html files containing the output of the corresponding view of model objects in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am just wondering whether there is any work regarding the generation of static html files containing the output of the corresponding view of model objects.

Such an approach should also be able to regenerate outdated html files in case model object content changes.

I have done some research but couldn't find any appropriate solution...

Comment: page caching does it so you should dig this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to parse–some steps/examples of what you're trying to accomplish would help.

*"output of the corresponding view of model objects"*

Model/objects don't have corresponding views–actions (in controllers) do. I'll assume you're talking about basic CRUD/scaffolding views related to your models.

If that's the case, take a look at [render_to_string](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465). It's basically renders a view to a string instead of to the browser.

So, if you wanted some "automatic" generation of html files, you could have a special controller action that loaded some models, looped through them, rendered a view for each to a string, and then saved that string to an HTML file using the model's ID and a time stamp as the name.

If you wanted to get *really* automatic, you could then call the URL of your special controller action daily/weekly/monthly from a cron job using wget (with some authentication, natch).